# expand wrapped inline script in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having large inline javascript script in my page and in Chrome dev tools I see it's being wrapped at some point (see threepoints):

[image]

I want to debug some code after this three dots. How can I access it how set a breakpoint?

Comment: Do you use Sources tab or Elements?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the triangle to the left of `<style>`, or double-click the `...`

Comment: You can also select different nodes using the `Up Arrow` and `Down Arrow` keys. The `Right Arrow` key expands a collapsed node. And the `Left Arrow` key collapses an expanded node.